# How do I register an Arbitrary instance in FsCheck and have xUnit use it?

Tags: f#, xunit, fscheck

I've got a type `Average` with a field `count` that's a positive `int64` and a `double` field called `sum`.

I made an arbitrary that generates valid instances with

```
 let AverageGen = Gen.map2 (fun s c -> Average(float(s),int64(int(c))) (Arb.Default.NormalFloat().Generator)  (Arb.Default.PositiveInt().Generator) |> Arb.fromGen
```

How do I get this to be generate arguments with type Average in `Property` style tests in xUnit?

```
[<Property>]
static member average_test(av:Average) = ...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
type Generators =
    static member TestCase() =
        { new Arbitrary<TestCase>() with
            override x.Generator =
                gen { ...
                      return TestCase(...) }}

[<Property(Arbitrary=[|typeof<Generators>|])>]
```

Comment: +1 But, shouldn't it be `new Arbitrary<Average>()...`?

Comment: c#:
 
`[Property(Arbitrary = new Type[] {typeof(Generators)})]`

Answer (score 5):

I think Vasily Kirichenko's solution is the correct one, but just for completeness sake, [I've also been able to make it work with this imperative function invocation](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/03/11/arbitrary-version-instances-with-fscheck) style:

```
do Arb.register<Generators>() |> ignore
```

...if you assume a `Generators` class as in Vasily Kirichenko's answer.

---

**Edit, much later...**

While the above, imperative approach may work, **I never use it** because of its impure nature. Instead, I sometimes [use the Arbitrary directly from within the test](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/09/08/ad-hoc-arbitraries-with-fscheckxunit). With the `AverageGen` value above (which I'll rename to `averageGen`, because values should be camelCased), it could look like this:

```
[<Property>]
let member average_test () =
    Prop.forAll averageGen (fun avg ->
        // The rest of the test goes here... )
```

Comment: I have never gotten Arb.register to work for me. Lately with Expecto I get "The type MyType is not handled automatically by FsCheck. Consider using another type or writing and registering a generator for it."
  
type DomainGenerators =
   static member MyType () =
            {new Arbitrary<MyType >() with
                override __.Generator = 
                    ...
                     }

do Arb.register<DomainGenerators>() |> ignore

[<Tests>]
...
 testPropertyWithConfig config10k "equality" <|
                fun  (myType : MyType) -> ...

Comment: Pretty sure now, my problem is a bug in Expecto. Registering does work the way I expect outside of Expecto. I'll be documenting and raising an issue soon.