# Generating custom data in FsCheck

Tags: f#, fscheck

I’ve got an `FsCheck` question:
I have the following record type (and I say upfront, I have been told that my Single-Case DUs are maybe an overkill, but I find them descriptive of the domain, and therefore necessary, and I will not remove them unless must):

```
type Name = Name of string
type Quality = Quality of int
type ShelfLife = Days of int
type Style = Plain | Aged | Legendary

type Item = {
    Name: Name
    Quality: Quality
    ShelfLife: ShelfLife
    Style: Style
}
```

Assuming I already have defined the functions `repeat: Int -> ('a -> 'a) -> 'a` and `decreaseQuality: Item -> Item`, I want to code an `FsCheck` test that checks the invariant: *Any item with style OTHER THAN Legendary, after 100 days have passed, has quality of 0*.

My problem is I don’t know the following things about `FsCheck`:
1. How do I define a custom generator that generates items whose style is not Legendary? And in contrast, how do I define items *only* of type Legendary (to test both types)?

I’ve looked into:

```
 let itemGenerator = Arb.generate<Item>
 Gen.sample 80 5 itemGenerator
```

but that creates Items that are plain weird, as the `size` controller, in the example, 80, controls also the length of the `Name of string` (due to the `of string`) and also produces `Quality` and `ShelfLife` values that are unacceptable to my domain (i.e. negative) as they are both defined as `... of int` which the size also controls.
(I’ve also looked into `Gen.oneof...`, but that turned out to also be a dud).

2. How do I even define a test that only tests the Quality property of the record, even assuming I found out a way to generate custom data?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of what you want becomes easy once you know how to use the `gen { }` computation expression to maximum effect.

First, I'll tackle how to generate a `Style` that isn't Legendary. You could use `Gen.oneOf`, but in this case I think it's simpler to use `Gen.elements`, since `oneOf` takes a sequence of *generators* to use, but `elements` just takes a list of items and generates one item from that list. So to generate a `Style` that isn't Legendary, I'd use `Gen.elements [Plain; Aged]`. (And to generate a `Style` that *is* Legendary, I'd just not use a generator and simply assign Legendary to the appropriate record field, but more on that later.)

As for names being too long, to limit the size of the strings produced to, say, a maximum of 15 characters, I'd use:

```
let genString15 = Gen.sized (fun s -> Gen.resize (min s 15) Arb.generate<string>)
// Note: "min" is not a typo. We want either s or 15, whichever is SMALLER
Gen.sample 80 5 genString15
// Never produces any strings longer than 15 characters
```

But this can still generate `null` strings, so I'd probably use this for my final version:

```
let genString15 =
    Gen.sized (fun s -> Gen.resize (min s 15) Arb.generate<NonNull<string>>)
    |> Gen.map (fun (NonNull x) -> x)  // Unwrap
Gen.sample 80 5 genString15
// Never produces any strings longer than 15 characters, AND never produces null
```

Now, since `Quality` and `ShelfLife` both can't be negative, I'd use either `PositiveInt` (where 0 isn't allowed either) or `NonNegativeInt` (which allows 0). Neither one is well documented in the FsCheck documentation, but they work like this:

```
let x = Arb.generate<NonNegativeInt>
Gen.sample 80 5 x
// Produces [NonNegativeInt 79; NonNegativeInt 75; NonNegativeInt 0;
//           NonNegativeInt 69; NonNegativeInt 16] which is hard to deal with
let y = Arb.generate<NonNegativeInt> |> Gen.map (fun (NonNegativeInt n) -> n)
Gen.sample 80 5 y
// Much better: [79; 75; 0; 69; 16]
```

To avoid duplicating code between generators for `Quality` and `Days`, I'd write something like the following:

```
let genNonNegativeOf (f : int -> 'a) = gen {
    let! (NonNegativeInt n) = Arb.generate<NonNegativeInt>
    return (f n)
}
Gen.sample 80 5 (genNonNegativeOf Quality)
// Produces: [Quality 79; Quality 35; Quality 2; Quality 42; Quality 73]
Gen.sample 80 5 (genNonNegativeOf Days)
// Produces: [Days 60; Days 27; Days 50; Days 22; Days 23]
```

And finally, let's tie that all together in a nice, elegant fashion with a `gen { }` CE:

```
let genNonLegendaryItem = gen {
    let! name = genString15 |> Gen.map Name
    let! quality = genNonNegativeOf Quality
    let! shelfLife = genNonNegativeOf Days
    let! style = Gen.elements [Plain; Aged]
    return {
        Name = name
        Quality = quality
        ShelfLife = shelfLife
        Style = style
    }
}
let genLegendaryItem =
    // This is the simplest way to avoid code duplication
    genNonLegendaryItem
    |> Gen.map (fun item -> { item with Style = Legendary })
```

Then once you've done that, to actually use this in your tests, you'll need to register the generators, as Tarmil mentioned in his answer. I'd probably use single-case DUs here so that the tests are easy to write, like this:

```
type LegendaryItem = LegendaryItem of Item
type NonLegendaryItem = NonLegendaryItem of Item
```

Then you'd register the `genLegendaryItem` and `genNonLegendaryItem` generators as producing `(Non)LegendaryItem` types by passing them through a `Gen.map`. And then your test cases would look like this (I'll use [Expecto](https://github.com/haf/expecto/) for my example here):

```
[<Tests>]
let tests =
    testList "Item expiration" [
        testProperty "Non-legendary items expire after 100 days" <| fun (NonLegendaryItem item) ->
            let itemAfter100Days = item |> repeat 100 decreaseQuality
            itemAfter100Days.Quality = Quality 0
        testProperty "Legendary items never expire" <| fun (LegendaryItem item) ->
            let itemAfter100Days = item |> repeat 100 decreaseQuality
            itemAfter100Days.Quality > Quality 0
    ]
```

Note that with this approach, you'd basically have to write the shrinkers yourself, whereas using `Arb.convert` as Tarmil suggested would get you shrinkers "for free". Don't underestimate the value of shrinkers, but if you find you can live without them, I like the nice, clean nature of the `gen { }` computation expression, and how easy it is to read the resulting code.

Comment: @O.F. BTW, the resource that taught me how to use the `gen` CE was Scott Wlaschin's explanation of computation expressions in general: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/computation-expressions.html

Comment: Tarmil's answer shows you how to register a type, so I didn't duplicate it. I mentioned passing it through `Gen.map` to turn the `Gen<Item>` I showed you into a `Gen<NonLegendaryItem>` which is what you want to register. I don't have time to type up a full example right now, but see https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/TestData.html, or https://stackoverflow.com/q/22719569/ if you're using XUnit. If you're using Expecto, you can do `let myConfig = { FsCheckConfig.defaultConfig with arbitrary = [typeof<MyGenerators>] }` then `testPropertyWithConfig myConfig <| fun (LegendaryItem item) -> ...`.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll look at the resources you mentioned and figure the rest out.

Comment: I'll just mention that if you're using Expecto, the `with arbitrary = [typeof<MyGenerators>]` (or `typeof<Arbs>` with the name that Tarmil used) *replaces* the call to `Arb.register<Arbs>()`. The reason Expecto needs something else is because Expecto launches your tests in parallel, each on a different thread, and the imperative-style `Arb.register<MyGenerators>()` call would only register them on the thread that put together the list of tests, which is *not* the thread that's running them. The Expecto example in my previous comment comes straight from code of mine that works, BTW.

Answer (score 2):

To always generate valid `Quality` and `ShelfLife`, you need to register Arbitrary instances:

```
type Arbs =
    static member Quality() =
        Arb.Default.NonNegativeInt()
        |> Arb.convert (fun (NonNegativeInt x) -> Quality x) (fun (Quality x) -> NonNegativeInt x)

    static member ShelfLife() =
        Arb.Default.NonNegativeInt()
        |> Arb.convert (fun (NonNegativeInt x) -> ShelfLife x) (fun (ShelfLife x) -> NonNegativeInt x)

Arb.register<Arbs>()
```

For the actual property you want to check, here's a rewording that will help translate it to FsCheck: IF Style is not Legendary, THEN after 100 days the quality is 0. In code:

```
let ``Non-legendary item breaks after 100 days`` (item: Item) =
    (item.Style <> Legendary) ==>
        let agedItem = item |> repeat 100 decreaseQuality
        agedItem.Quality = Quality 0
```

Comment: (A previous comment of mine seems to have been removed...)
Thank you for showing me how to correctly use the `Arb` class, and in relation to my use-case specifically.
Also for rewording my invariant so it makes sense, test-wise.
Really helpful stuff!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After resolving all the issues I had with understanding `FsCheck` usage (for the moment, I'm sure I'll have more issues in the future), [this is the repo](https://github.com/OmanF/gilded_rose) with my entire solution.

Obviously, the tests code is in the (I think aptly named) `GildedRoseTests` folder.

I have used the `gen` computation expression method, suggested by rmunn above, but a different experiment I did, using Tarmil's `Arb` method works just as well (and you get shrinking "for free").